# How to run Oracle Client 10g from non Administrator account?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, client, windows-10

Hi I have 2 users configured on my Windows 10 Home machine. One is Administrator and another is my own user. Although my user is configured as an Administrator, I can use Oracle Client 10g from my Administrator account only. Is there any way in which I do not have to switch to the Administrator account and still be able to use Oracle Client 10g from my own account ?

Comment: ,what you want to run for oracle 10g from user account?

Comment: OraEdit Ver 4.0. It opens up fine but cannot connect to remote oracle database. But it does in Administrator account.

Comment: Did you try in user account , for open OraEdit 4.0 editor, to run with administrator account. may be it will ask the permission of administrator and you will be able to do .

Comment: I tried doing that, but I think it depends on other modules as well and until they also run in Administrator mode, it doesn't work out. Maybe if there is a way to run the whole Oracle Client 10g as an Administrator, then it could work out. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Oracle Client 10g instead of the current version 12c.  Oracle is very good at backward compatibility.   10g is from a time when Administrator access wasn't well enforced.

Comment: could you please post the exact error message?